# Effect of iOS 7 update on my app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios7

I have an app released on the app store and I am still working on my iOS 7 update. How will the upgrade to iOS 7 affect the version of my app that is already out there? Will the users who have upgraded still be able to use the existing version?

Comment: Have you tested your application on iOS7?

Comment: depends how you release it. if you release it as an update, it will be just as any update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app was built with Xcode 4 and the iOS 6 SDK, it will look the same on iOS 7, except for UIAlertViews and UIActionSheets.

If you make an update to your app with Xcode 5 and the iOS 7 SDK, all UI elements will be updated.

Apple hasn't said how much longer you can submit apps using Xcode 4, but it won't be forever.

Comment: Also, my mac runs Snow Leopard. I heard I need Mountain Lion for iOS 7 development. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, 10.8.4 or higher

Comment: OS X Mavericks will be released around October so just wait for that.

Answer (score 3):

If your existing app uses any native controls and ui, it will change in the upgraded iOS. So if you have a navigation bar translucent in your current app, it will show up as the iOS 7 navigation bar translucent. If you have Custom buttons, they will stay unchanged. They will still be there.

So my answer is: Depends.
If you have all the native controls, it will be changed to iOS 7 elements.
If you have all the custom controls (custom buttons, backgrounds etc.), it will not be effected.
Try to look into iOS 7 transition guide once its available.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't have a device where I can run iOS 7 beta. I'm counting on the stable release due today. I will check my app then. Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: Actually, as far as I know, an app built with an iOS6 target (so one already on the app store) will look the same on iOS7 - I've tested this on an app I have using native UINavigationControllers and UITabBarControllers.

Comment: I strongly believe my answer is right because I have studied it up in the transition guide which is currently beta. So I cant share the link

Comment: @Aaron How is the answer wrong? In my experience everything that he said was true.

Comment: Do I need to upgrade my Mac to Mountain Lion for this purpose? It currently runs Snow Leopard.

Comment: Yes. Xcode 5 doesnt run on Lion as well. It is supported from Mountain Lion Version.

Comment: Xcode 5 requires 10.8.4.  This answer is wrong because Apps built against the iOS 6 SDK will not get an iOS 7 appearance just because a user updates to iOS 7.

Comment: I agree to all the above comments. It was my mistake and assumption

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how will the existing version of your app work on iOS 7, then, the simple answer is: try it!